# Vue Router best practice: Redirect in store or component?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuex, vue-router

Say you have something like a `signOut()` action in your Vuex store and you want to redirect to the homepage after the user pressed the corresponding button. Should I do the redirect in the component where the button lives or in the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends :-)

I would say that in general case store is something independent on router.
And I would try avoid touching router from state.

Especially in case you are using Nuxt (which is not your case) there is no clean way to obtain router instance (yes, you can hack it using this._vm)

Anyway if you have an action bound linked to navigation you can beat the rule for practical reasons. Still I would try to extract routing logic out of the store. (eg. listen to change from outside, maybe root component, and navigate from there etc.)

Really depends on you scenario and there is no 100% clear answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `Promise` from action and handle it inside component's method.

Vuex store:

```js
const actions = {
  signOut({ commit }) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      commit("SET_CREDENTIALS", null);
      resolve();
    })
  }
};
```

Your component's method section:

```js
methods: {
  signOut() {
   this.$store.dispatch("signOut")
     .then(() => this.$router.push("/home"));
  }
},
```